# Reload Redis DB

Tags: redis

I am using redis with rails 2.3.8 to keep track of high scores and I just rebooted my server and the DB is not reloading.  The default dir path for the DB in the config file was being used: 'dir ./' I think?  And the dbfilename name was set to the default as well: ' dbfilename dump.rdb'  Is there any way to restore this?  Was a DB file saved with the default settings or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis does save to disk regularly by default - as long as you didn't disable saving or point multiple instances at the same file it should reload automatically when you restart Redis.

However, the server will not automatically restart after a reboot unless you set up an init script for it. If you do have an init script but haven't rebooted before, you most likely have the scripted instance either using a different working directory or a different user that doesn't have permissions for the db file.

If the file specified in the config really doesn't exist, chances are you got something wrong in your initial configuration - saving is optional, so failure writing to disk is logged as a warning rather than a fatal error. If you had save errors in your log that you didn't deal with before rebooting there's not much you can do now.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your response.  I did not have an init script and manually started redis with the config file that was using the default 'dir ./' path to save the rdb file.  The default save options were also there, so stuff should have gotten saved to this file.  Do you have any idea the rdb file would be with these default settings?

Comment: BTW, I installed redis w instructions from here: http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html with cd redis-2.2.2, make, cp src/redis-server src/redis-cli /usr/bin

Comment: with those instructions, dump.rdb should be in whatever folder you were in when you first ran redis, assuming you had access to write to that folder. Checking the logs may help, though most likely not as the log directory is not writable by default.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when I restarted redis-server after a reboot, the dump.rdb was not picked up.  I had to explicitly specify the config file e.g. `redis-server etc/redis.conf` for it to pick up the dump.rdb.